# lib разных версий соответственно для dll разных версий

Tags: c++, dll, lib

На компьютере в разные папки установлено две версии одной сторонней программы prog1.0 и prog1.1. В папке каждой из них есть prog.dll (имена совпадают). С каждой версией программы поставляются prog.lib и prog.h для доступа к prog.dll. Я делаю программу, которая использует prog.dll:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "prog.lib" )
#include "prog.h"
...
//код программы...
```

Если файлы prog.lib и prog.h из комплекта prog1.0, то моя программа будет работать только с версией prog1.0.  И наоборот. Иначе ошибка "точка входа в процедуру... не найдена в библиотеке prog.dll". Я же хочу работоспособность сразу с двумя версиями.

Для работы с каждой из версий пробовал создать свой класс :

```
ClassProg1a pr1;
ClassProg1b pr2;
```

Далее в определение классов уже вписывал (файлы предварительно переименовал):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "prog1.lib" )
#include "prog1.h"
```

и

```
#pragma comment(lib, "prog2.lib" )
#include "prog2.h"
```

Компиляция успешна. Однако, при запуске все та же ошибка "точка входа в процедуру... не найдена в библиотеке prog.dll".

Как быть? Спасибо.

Comment: грузить вручную с помощью `LoadLibrary` и вручную привязывать точки входа к указателям на функции

Comment: Видимо вам придется пересобрать библиотеку импорта для одной из этих библиотек, чтобы они обе не пытались одновременно импортировать символы из одной и той же .dll.

Comment: @VTT у меня нет исходников, что бы сделать это

Comment: Сами .dll пересобирать не надо, только .lib, так что исходники не нужны. Можете даже срезать угол и попробовать переименовать имя линкуемой .dll непосредственно отредактировав .lib в каком-нибудь hex редакторе (не изменяя при этом длины имени).

Comment: @VTT  1) У меня нет исходников .lib файлов. Или их можно как-то напрямую редактировать? 2) dll переименовать нет возможности, программа ведь не моя 3) если я правильно понимаю, вместе с версией программы изменилась и версия dll. Соответственно, в каждой dll, предположительно, частично свой набор функций и их реализация. Другими словами, что бы моя программа работала с двумя программами, она должна корректно работать с обеими версиями dll. Т.е. мне как-то надо заставить мою программу по выбору динамически использовать ту или иную библиотеку импорта, а потом и нужную dll подключать в процессе.